# How to open a the kiosk mode through a link on a website

Tags: html, wordpress, browser, kiosk-mode

i have a problem. I want a page to open in a Firefox Kiosk mode through a link on a website. I am creating a website for schoolchildren through which it should be possible to take exams. The test pages for this should only be opened in kiosk mode to prevent cheating.

I hope someone has an idea.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inside a webpage can trigger Kiosk mode.

(It would be pretty awful if it was possible as any website could lock users into the browser and prevent them from quitting or using any other application!)

If you want to prevent students from using other applications (or webpages), then launch the browser in kiosk mode from the desktop.

If you want to prevent students from accessing data built into the webpage that would enable them to cheat (such as "This is the correct answer" values on checkboxes) then don't put that data into the page in the first place. Use tokens (such as "answer number 1") and resolve them server-side.